# method for add and update data from popup

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a pop up form from which new data can be added or old data can be updated. 
But I don't know how to write method for this condition. I mean in the case of new data entry I don't need the `Id` but in case of edit I need the `Id` attribute. The controller name is `Vehicle`.

```
   [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult AddorEdit([Bind(Include = "Id,VehicleType,Amount,RenewPeriod,Status")] Vehicle vehicle)
    {            
        vehicle.RegisteredDate = DateTime.Now;
        vehicle.RegisteredBy = "admin";

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Vehicle.Add(vehicle);
            db.SaveChanges();

        }
        return Json(new { success = true, message = "Saved Successfully" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

The jquery code of index page from where pop up is called ::

```
<a class="btn btn-success" style="margin-bottom:10px;" onclick="PopupForm('@Url.Action("AddorEdit", "Vehicles")')"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add New</a>

 <script>
        var Popup, dataTable;
        $(document).ready(function () {
            dataTable = $("#tbl_vehicle").DataTable({
                "ajax":{
                    "url": "/Vehicles/GetVehicle",
                    "type": "GET", 
                    "datatype": "json"
                },
                "columns": [
                    { "data": "VehicleType" },
                    { "data": "Amount" },
                    { "data": "RenewPeriod" },
                    { "data": "RegisteredDate" },
                    { "data": "RegisteredBy" },
                    { "data": "Status" },
                    { "data": "ModifiedBy" },
                    { "data": "ModifiedDate" }
                ],
                "language": {
                    "emptyTable" : "No data available, please click on <b>Add</b> button"
                }

            });

        });

        function PopupForm(url) {
            var formDiv = $('<div/>');
            $.get(url).done(function (response) {
                formDiv.html(response);

                Popup = formDiv.dialog({
                    autoOpen: true,
                    resizable: false, 
                    title: 'fill details',
                    height: 500,
                    width: 700,
                    close: function () {
                        Popup.dialog('destroy').remove();
                    }
                });
            });
        }

        function SubmitForm(form) {
            alert("testing....");
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: form.action,
                data: $(form).serialize(),
                success: function (date) {
                    if(data.success)
                    {
                        Popup.dialog('close');
                        dataTable.ajax.reload();
                    }
                }
            });
            return false;
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Are you submitting popup by `ajax`? Why don't you use `Jquery` to get the value of `ID` ? Give us your submitting method, Pls.

Comment: @Anonymous yes I am using `ajax`. I have added the code too. Please check. Thank You!!!

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to handle this by making id as a `HiddenField` so when ever user post data to the server you can query the id field.
 whether it has value or not and decide which operation you should perform i.e. Add operation if id is null/empty and Edit Operation if Id has the value.

Please use below code section for reference :

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult AddorEdit([Bind(Include = "Id,VehicleType,Amount,RenewPeriod,Status")] Vehicle vehicle)
{ 
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
         if(vehicle.Id <= 0)
         {
                vehicle.RegisteredDate = DateTime.Now;
                vehicle.RegisteredBy = "admin";
                 db.Vehicle.Add(vehicle);
         } 
         else
            {
             db.Entry(vehicle).State = EntityState.Modified;
             //perform more checks if you want    
            }

       db.SaveChanges();
     }
    return Json(new { success = true, message = "Saved Successfully" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: Yes I have created a hidden field in the pop up form too, but I think my `AddorEdit` method is not properly written too. Please can you verify once. Thank You!!!

Comment: @nischalinn I have updated my answer. please check.

Comment: Thank You for the reply. I have one next query, how can I show json message 'Updated successfully' in case of record Update and 'Added Successfully' in case of record Added. Thank You!!!

Comment: @nischalinn, Instead of returning saved successfully what you can do is you can return instantly once record is updated or added by storing appropriate messages that you want to show on client side. I prefer a common object/model across application which stores message to be displayed on client side, request status and data that you want to pass along with it. Also mark my answer if you solved your original question :)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by this simple way

```
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if(vehicle.Id <= 0)
        {
          vehicle.RegisteredDate = DateTime.Now;
          vehicle.RegisteredBy = "admin";
          db.Vehicle.Add(vehicle);
        } 
        else
         db.Entry(vehicle).State = EntityState.Modified;

        db.SaveChanges();

    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? Let me know if you need any help @nischalinn